# Why am I getting prompted for credentials when attempting to deploy SSRS report?

Tags: reporting-services

This error is across the board for all accounts. Nobody is able to deploy any SSR reports. SSRS has just been installed on this server.
I am getting prompted for credentials when attempting to deploy a report from Visual Studio. Also, Windows App Event viewer shows this error:

Failed to initialize the AppDomain:ReportServer_SSRS_1
Exception: System.UnauthorizedAccessException
Message: Access to the path 'Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services\SSRS\ReportServer\RSTempFiles~AspAccessCheck_4a1815238420.tmp' is denied.

Note: Service account has Read and Write access to the folder in the error.

Few facts:
My account is member of  System Administrator role  on the SSRS site.
My account is also member of Content Manager role in the root of the SSRS site.
TargetServerURL in the Integration Services Project is set to https://someserver/reportserver.
Service Account is built-in VirtualService Account
Current Report Server Database Credential is a domain account. After setting this up, the account was granted proper access to master, ReportServer, ReportServerTempDB databases.
Seemingly identical settings are on another server and on this server we are able to deploy reports without any problems.

Is there a setting that I might have missed when setting up SSRS server that is causing the problem of not being able to deploy reports?

Comment: You said the target was set to https://localhost/reportserver in Integration Services Project? Two things, `1.` are you developing and deploying from and the the same machine, localhost would suggest you are, try putting in the actual address of the server. `.2.` did you mean to say Reporting Services Project as this is where you would normally state the report server as the target.

Comment: Apologies for not being clear.
https://localhost/reportserver - I meant it as an example. I am not deploying on the same machine. I should have stated https://someserver/reportserver. I ma attempting to deploy a report i n Integration Services Project to a remote machine.